# Off topic close reasons no longer include "provide code"?

Tags: discussion

Until recently, when you selected "close" on a question, the menu of options that was presented looked a lot like the one being described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185142/212464) (if my memory serves me right).

Today I wanted to vote to close a question that lacked the "demonstrate minimal understanding, show code" criterion (#2 and #3 in above link). It seems that the options were changed.

When did they get changed, and why?

Comment: Often such questions are "too broad" or "unclear", those that aren't are now on topic. While I would have liked more community involvement before this decision was taken I can get behind that as long as "too broad" is enforced strictly